# Accessing object values with generic method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, refactoring

I'm doing some refactoring and trying to create a generic method which is able to populate given dropdowns with object data. However I'm coming up against an issue regarding how to make accessing different object data generic. For example:

Original method

```
function populateDropdown(element, data) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    element.append('<option value=' + data[i].ID + '>' + data[i].Name + '</option>');
}
```

This works if a given array of objects has the field `ID` and `Name`. What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
function populateDropdown(element, data, valueField, dataField) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    element.append('<option value=' + data[i].valueField + '>' + data[i].dataField + '</option>');
}
```

When I've tried calling this method like this I get `Undefined` as a result: `populateDropdown($('#myDropdown'), dataArray, "ID", "DataType");`

And when I've tried without the `""` I get a console error saying that `ID` and `DataType` isn't defined. Is there a way to tell my method what fields I want from the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) -

```
function populateDropdown(element, data, valueField, dataField) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        element.append('<option value=' + data[i][valueField] + '>' + data[i][dataField] + '</option>');
}
```

Note - to make this a little more resilient to special characters in the property values, I would do this instead:

```
$('<option />', { value : data[i][valueField] }).text(data[i][dataField]).appendTo(element);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jason that's worked! Lots of great answers but you were the first to post so the answered vote goes to you when the time allows :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do `data[i][valueField]`and `data[i][dataField]`:

```
function populateDropdown(element, data, valueField, dataField) {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    element.append('<option value=' + data[i][valueField] + '>' + data[i][dataField] + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) `[]` to access the properties:

```
function populateDropdown(element, data, valueField, dataField) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        element.append('<option value=' + data[i][valueField] + '>' + data[i][dataField] + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the others said, not sure if this is helpful, just fyi you can also define default values if you don't pass them like so...

```
function populateDropdown(element, data, valueField, dataField) {
    valueField = valueField || 'some_default_value';
    dataField = dataField || 'some_default_value';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        element.append('<option value=' + data[i][valueField] + '>' + data[i][dataField] + '</option>');
}
```

Then you can call it like this, leaving valueField and dataField params out:

```
populateDropdown('someElement', 'someValue');
```